# Why the desc command does not produce any statistics or explain plan?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Why the **desc** command does not produce any statistics or explain plan when I query, for example: `desc my_table` ?

Comment: Why should it? That isn't what it does.

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative, use [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).

And instead of DESC, try INFO+

You get everything that DESC shows, but so much more. And with the (+), SQLcl adds the stats on the columns.

```
SQL> info+ regions
TABLE: REGIONS 
     LAST ANALYZED:2019-10-14 11:11:42.0 
     ROWS         :4 
     SAMPLE SIZE  :4 
     INMEMORY     :DISABLED 
     COMMENTS     :Regions table that contains region numbers and names. Contains 4 rows; references with the Countries table. 

Columns 
NAME          DATA TYPE           NULL  DEFAULT    LOW_VALUE   HIGH_VALUE               NUM_DISTINCT   HISTOGRAM  
*REGION_ID    NUMBER              No                   1           4                        4              NONE       
 REGION_NAME  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)   Yes                  Americas    Middle East and Africa   4              NONE       

Indexes
     INDEX_NAME    UNIQUENESS    STATUS    FUNCIDX_STATUS      COLUMNS 
_______________ _____________ _________ _________________ ____________ 
HR.REG_ID_PK    UNIQUE        VALID                       REGION_ID    


References
   TABLE_NAME    CONSTRAINT_NAME    DELETE_RULE     STATUS        DEFERRABLE    VALIDATED    GENERATED 
_____________ __________________ ______________ __________ _________________ ____________ ____________ 
COUNTRIES     COUNTR_REG_FK      NO ACTION      ENABLED    NOT DEFERRABLE    VALIDATED    USER NAME    

SQL>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.2/SQCQR/toc.htm#SQCQR-GUID-E409CC44-9A8F-4043-82C8-6B95CD939296)...

INFO[RMATION] {[schema.]object[@connect_identifier]}
Lists more detailed information about the column definitions for a table, view or synonym, or the specifications for a function or procedure.

Note:

INFORMATION+ will show column statistics.

Comment: You just made my day!  Wish I could upvote multiple times!!

Comment: Once is more than enough Justin :)

Comment: Works in SQL Developer too.  Thanks @thatjeffsmith

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm):

> ## DESCRIBE
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> DESC[RIBE] {[schema.]object[@db_link]}
> ```
>
> Lists the column definitions for the specified table, view or synonym, or the specifications for the specified function or procedure.
>
> **Usage**
>
> The description for tables, views, types and synonyms contains the following information:
>
> - each column's name
> - whether or not null values are allowed (`NULL` or `NOT NULL`) for each column
> - datatype of columns, for example, `CHAR`, `DATE`, `LONG`, `LONGRAW`, `NUMBER`, `RAW`, `ROWID`, `VARCHAR2` (`VARCHAR`), or `XMLType`
> - precision of columns (and scale, if any, for a numeric column)

So all it does is lists the column definitions or specifications.

> Why the `desc` command does not produce any statistics or explain planwhen I query, for example: `desc my_table`?

Because they aren't column definitions for the table and the `DESCRIBE` command is doing exactly what it was intended to do; no more, no less.